# Why do am i able to login to MariaDB using anything with XAMPP on Windows 7

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

i'm new around xampp on windows 7, usually i uses mariadb on a debian.

i notice something strange recently, the default root doesn't have a password ikr but the problem for me is why do i'm able to login to MariaDB using anything and i mean literally anything that doesn't even belonged to an existing username.

ex :
mysql -u johndoe

i can login using that kind of username eventhough there's no johndoe user, it's not a big problem though because eventhough i can login using that username i can't do anything because those users doesn't had any access yet, but my question is why is it happening? and how to stop it?

thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to the database as `root`. Make sure you are really `root` by running

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER();
```

It should show `root`@`localhost` or something else that has `root` as a username. Then run

```
SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
```

If it returns anything, then it's the reason why you can connect with non-existing user names -- you have so-called *anonymous accounts*.

To stop it, run

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: by the way, why is this happening? is it xampp defaut? or a mistake i made?

Comment: @germa66 : It's a legacy, default installation. In some packages/installation scripts these anonymous accounts get removed, in others they remain for the superuser to decide what to do about them. If you ran an interactive installer on Windows, I think it actually asks what to do with anonymous accounts, so, if you used it, you probably confirmed that they should be created

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, i don't quiet remember that the interactive installer on Windows asked me about it, maybe i missed it or forgot about it, but i'll find that out for sure later. thanks a lot for your help.